# Store input field to cookie on ahref click

Tags: javascript, php

I need to store the content sitting in form > input via a $_cookie or $_session when the user clicks the ahref url

```html
<form>
  <input id="sccomment" type="text" placeholder="Leave a comment on Soundcloud" />
</form>
                                  
<a id="link" href="<?php echo $soundcloud_auth_url; ?>" class="btn-sc fw">Connect with Soundcloud</a>
```

Comment: You can use either javascript of PHP.

Comment: you can create a PHP page and OnClick post the data for storing before redirect

Comment: Yes but the link goes to a OAuth page so I need the data stored for after the OAuth and completed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function submitData(url){
var sccomment = document.getElementById("sccomment").value;
document.cookie = "sccomment="+sccomment;
window.location.href=url;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="sccomment" type="text" placeholder="Leave a comment on Soundcloud" />
</form>
                                  
<a id="link" onClick="submitData('<?php echo $soundcloud_auth_url; ?>');" class="btn-sc fw">Connect with Soundcloud</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you actually want to persist an unsubmitted comment if the user navigates away from the page using any means, so they don't lose everything.

To solve this in a reusable way, you can use this: ([working demo](https://codepen.io/LeeKowalkowski/pen/RMgEqz))

```
var persistInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-persist=true]');

for(var i = 0; i < persistInputs.length; i++) {
  var input = persistInputs[i];

  input.persistName = 'persist-' + input.name;
  input.value = localStorage[input.persistName] || input.value;

  input.onchange = function(){localStorage[this.persistName] = this.value;};
}

var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  forms[i].onsubmit = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < persistInputs.length; i++) {
      var input = persistInputs[i];

      if(this == input.form) {
        localStorage.removeItem(input.persistName);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any text input you want to stay until submitted add the attribute `data-persist="true"`:

```
<form method="post">
  <label>Persisted comment: <input name="persisted-comment" data-persist="true"></label>
  <label>Ordinary comment: <input name="ordinary-comment"></label>
  <button>Send comment</button>
</form>
```

I chose to use `localStorage` for persistence because that unsubmitted data will not be accessible to the server, it's kind of a privacy issue to submit data to your server without the user's explicit consent, I didn't want to go there, really... kinda evil.